# Error message starting gis.m in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis

I finally broke down and bought Neteler and Mitasova's book, Open Source GIS: A GRASS GIS Approach, because I need to learn command-line GRASS. On trying to work through the book's examples, I'm finding that there may be a problem with my GRASS installation, or more likely with the installation of the tk framework. Here's the code and the error message that I'm getting:

> gregory@Gregorys-MacBook> gis.m
>   ~ gregory@Gregorys-MacBook> /usr/local/bin/wish: line 2:
>   /usr/local/bin/../../../Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Wish.app/Contents/MacOS/Wish:
>   No such file or directory

I installed GRASS and its dependencies using the binary installers from KyngChaos, so I'm pretty confident that the TK framework got installed correctly, but the error message seems to indicate otherwise. Also, I don't know how to interpret the section of the path in the error message that reads "/../../../".

Can anyone suggest a fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the book is rather old and meanwhile, the GUI written in Tk (gis.m and d.m TCL/TK-based GUI frontend) was replaced by a new GUI, written in wxPython (wxGUI wxPython-based GUI frontend) (see [GRASS GUI[1](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_GUI))

As you use the [KyngChaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/grass) version, you start GRASS GIS by:

- double clicking GRASS-6.4 application
- or from the shell (Terminal.app) using

[image]

It is the same thing because the application calls this script grass.sh which open the GRASS shell and the wxGUI wxPython-based GUI frontend:

[image]

If you want to use the old TCL/TK-based GUI frontend (unsupported now)

- use gis.m in the GRASS shell (the easy way):

[image]

[image]

- or change the value of GRASS_GUI in the file **.grassrc6** in your home directory:

  GRASS_GUI: wxpython to GRASS_GUI: tcltk

Comment: Thanks, Gene. I see no reason to use the older unsupported GUI. I'll just have to figure out how to deal with aspects of the book that are out of date. It is very frustrating to pay $85 for an eBook that is out of date, however.

Comment: I learn GRASS with this book. It gives you the basics With the exception of the GUI, the processing operations remain valid.